# How do I get multiple conditionals to run inside a while loop if the boolean of the conditional is true?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write a repeat-while loop, that has multiple conditional statements inside it in swift.

If the string has a character then it will replace that character with a string. If the string doesn't then it will check the next conditional.

The code will loop through until all conditionals boolean are false, or it has reached the count of textCount.

Simple enough, right? But it only changes one character at a time, and if there is "a" and a "b" character it will only change the "b".

I've tried using switch case's with the string turned into an array, but for some reason couldn't count the elements in the array so settled with a while loop.

Feel free to correct my logic if I'm wrong so I can learn from my mistakes!

```
    let text = textInput.text!.lowercased()
    var textCount = text.count
    var loopCount = 0

    repeat {

        if text.contains("a") {
            textCount = text.count
            loopCount = loopCount + 1
            let newText = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "a", with: ".-")
            inputResult.text = newText

        } else if text.contains("b") {
            textCount = text.count
            loopCount = loopCount + 1
            let newText = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "b", with: "-...")
            inputResult.text = newText
        }

    } while loopCount <= textCount
```

Comment: Why not executing all the  `newtext = text.replacingOccurrences` one after the other without the loop? I don't see the reason to make a loop here and in the end you only need all the characters replaced by their string replacements

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Are you saying that if the string contains "a" and "b" we should replace "a" and _stop_ or that we should replace "a" and go on to "b" as well? Give examples of possible input and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If are you trying to implement some kind of Morse encoding, I suggest to create a dictionary for all letters first, then  simply loop through it:

```
let cipher = ["a": ".-", "b": "-...", "c": "-.-.", <...and so on...>]

  for pair in cipher {
    text = text.replacingOccurrences(of: pair.key, with: pair.value)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong this is what you are asking for:

```
let text = textInput.text!.lowercased()
let newText = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "a", with: ".-")
newText = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "b", with: "-...")
newText = text.replacingOccurrences...
inputResult.text = newText
```